# What does “yield” do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yield

What does `yield` do in ruby on rails?

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".sidebar">
  <!-- Your timezone is <%= Time.zone %> -->
  <!-- <%= "Ruby Version is #{RUBY_VERSION}" if Rails.env =~ /test|development/ %> -->
  <%= render partial:'shared/account_status' %>
  <%= render partial:"shared/session_timeout" %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= render partial:"shared/branding" %>
    <%= render partial:"shared/nav", locals:{icons:icons, actionable_urls:actionable_urls, top_level_items:MenuItem.top_level_items_with_access_rights_for_user(current_user).sort{|a, b| a.sequence <=> b.sequence}, current_item:current_navigation_item} %>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div id="content">
      <%= render partial:"shared/flash", object:flash %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

  </div>
  <%= render partial:"shared/ldap_user_menu" if signed_in_as_ldap_user?  %>
</body>
```

Comment: “What does `yield` do in ruby on rails?”—absolutely the same thing it does in pure Ruby. Yields to the block. It’s not Rails-specific.

Comment: It loads page contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tells Rails to put your view content to this block (which is called by `yield`) at that place in the layout file.

Checkout the rails guide to learn more about the ActionView.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html

As pointed out by @Aleksei Matiushkin, `yield` is pure ruby, so you should also learn more about that in your own time.

Here's a (**my**) visual presentation to explain what happened on that line:

**view.html.erb**:

```
<p>Hello there!</p>
<p>I'm a content from view</p>
```

**layout.html.erb**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the results will be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Hello there!</p>
    <p>I'm a content from view</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does not tell anything _Rails_. Rails has nothing to do with `yield`. ERB is pure ruby, and `yield` is pure ruby.

Comment: Rails is a framework based on ruby. `yield` is ruby. Ruby tells Rails == It tells Rails. He's asking what did `yield` do in that line. Not what is `yield`. I'm sorry about the confusion. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @piabano What you wrote is not wrong. But is is only true when the OP has the ability to trace down the Rails code to figure out how that is implemented in the specific context of a Rails view system, in which case the OP would not have answered such question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not specific enough. In Rails, as with ordinary Ruby, `yield` used within a method definition represents the block that is passed to a method.

However, judging from the code block that you gave, you seem to particularly want to ask about `yield` used in layouts of a view in Rails. In such case, it represents the main content described in the view file that is to be rendered in the context. For example, when the controller is `Foo`, and the action is `bar`, then, `yield` used within a layout to be used in such context will be replaced by the content of `/app/views/foo/bar.html` (or whatever corresponding view file in other format).

Comment: And it’s still an invocation of the block from the ERB implementation under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

It must be simple in your concept: `yield` is where put content block (html) from action view to layout template
example: action index render `index.html`, the result will be put/filled in the `yield`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen `render` mentioned in the other answers, so I'd like to add to @vipibano's answer, that if you want to understand how this `yield` business works in Rails (and more specifically in the `application.html.erb`), you'll benefit from:

1. understanding how blocks work in Ruby (as mentioned by others)
2. understanding what Rails' `render` method does

The `render` method is called at the end of a controller action and orchestrates what block is passed to the method that is actually rendering the `application.html.erb`.

I've tried to visualize this a bit and there a few examples if you want to dig deeper in the according post:

https://richstone.io/debunk/

[image]